# Using an UPDATE Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am currently trying to create a stored procedure that will be used to UPDATE a table. I am running into an issue where the code says it executes, affects every line but nothing updates. I want to be able to update information in a single row at a time and have the row actually update.

Code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTrail  
    (@Open char(3),
     @AmountReal int,
     @AmountFake int) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TRAIL
    SET @Open = TOpen, 
        @AmountReal = AmountRealSnow, 
        @AmountFake = AmountFakeSnow

    RETURN @@Identity 
 END
```

My columns are the following in the `trail` table:

```
TrailID int identity primary key,
TrailName varchar(255) Unique, 
Topen char(3),
AmountReal int,
Amountfake int
```

Please, any suggestions?

Comment: Considering the names of things, i'd think you'd want to swap `@Open` and `TOpen` (and the same for the other parameters).

Comment: Yes. you are trying to update wrong thing. Use column name.. not the variable name.

Comment: @ViKiNG is right also why the `@@identity`?

Comment: And the worst thing is: the `UPDATE` command will update all rows in your `TRAIL` table while you don't specify the rows to be aupdated (`WHERE`)

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to return @@identity or any other related value. This is an **update** - any such value will have no meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the structure of an update statement s/b

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET myColumn = @variable
     , myCol2   = @var2
 WHERE myTable.filtercolumn = @variable
```

As suggested in comments by Sami, you will also need to pass in the record key to the stored procedure for the record to be updated.

something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTrail (@Key int, 
@Open              char(3),
@AmountReal        int,
@AmountFake        int
) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    Update TRAIL
    set TOpen = @Open
      , AmountRealSnow = @AmountReal
      , AmountFakeSnow = @AmountFake 
    Where TRAIL.TrailID = @Key
    Return @@Identity 
 END
```

Comment: So how would I execute the procedure to hit the trail with trail id = 1?

Comment: To execute a stored procedure with parameters you can do it as follows: exec UpdateTrail 1, 'abc', 2,3   OR   EXEC UpdateTrail \@Key =1, @Open='abc', \@AmountReal=3, \@AmountFake = 5

Comment: remove the escape('\') characters from the edit above